# React component does not update on set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to conditionally render a component based on toggling of flag inside state. It looks like the state is getting updated but the component is not getting rendered. Can some one tell what is wring here. `renderTree` function updates the state, but render is not called then.

```
import React from "react";
import CheckboxTree from "react-checkbox-tree";
import "react-checkbox-tree/lib/react-checkbox-tree.css";
import { build } from "../data";
import { Input, Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import _ from "lodash";

class Widget extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nodes: build(),
      checked: [],
      expanded: [],
      isDropdownExpanded: false,
      keyword: ""
    };
  }

  onCheck = checked => {
    this.setState({ checked }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.checked);
    });
  };

  onExpand = expanded => {
    this.setState({ expanded }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.expanded);
    });
  };

  renderTree = () => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          isDropdownExpanded: !prevState.isDropdownExpanded
        };
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };

  onSearchInputChange = (event, data, searchedNodes) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      if (prevState.keyword.trim() && !data.value.trim()) {
        return {
          expanded: [],
          keyword: data.value
        };
      }
      return {
        expanded: this.getAllValuesFromNodes(searchedNodes, true),
        keyword: data.value
      };
    });
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.keyword !== nextState.keyword) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!_.isEqual(this.state.checked, nextState.checked)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (_.isEqual(this.state.expanded, nextState.expanded)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  getAllValuesFromNodes = (nodes, firstLevel) => {
    if (firstLevel) {
      const values = [];
      for (let n of nodes) {
        values.push(n.value);
        if (n.children) {
          values.push(...this.getAllValuesFromNodes(n.children, false));
        }
      }
      return values;
    } else {
      const values = [];
      for (let n of nodes) {
        values.push(n.value);
        if (n.children) {
          values.push(...this.getAllValuesFromNodes(n.children, false));
        }
      }
      return values;
    }
  };

  keywordFilter = (nodes, keyword) => {
    let newNodes = [];
    for (let n of nodes) {
      if (n.children) {
        const nextNodes = this.keywordFilter(n.children, keyword);
        if (nextNodes.length > 0) {
          n.children = nextNodes;
        } else if (n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
          n.children = nextNodes.length > 0 ? nextNodes : [];
        }
        if (
          nextNodes.length > 0 ||
          n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          n.label = this.getHighlightText(n.label, keyword);
          newNodes.push(n);
        }
      } else {
        if (n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
          n.label = this.getHighlightText(n.label, keyword);
          newNodes.push(n);
        }
      }
    }
    return newNodes;
  };

  getHighlightText = (text, keyword) => {
    const startIndex = text.indexOf(keyword);
    return startIndex !== -1 ? (
      <span>
        {text.substring(0, startIndex)}
        <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
          {text.substring(startIndex, startIndex + keyword.length)}
        </span>
        {text.substring(startIndex + keyword.length)}
      </span>
    ) : (
      <span>{text}</span>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { checked, expanded, nodes, isDropdownExpanded } = this.state;
    let searchedNodes = this.state.keyword.trim()
      ? this.keywordFilter(_.cloneDeep(nodes), this.state.keyword)
      : nodes;
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown fluid selection options={[]} onClick={this.renderTree} />
        {isDropdownExpanded && (
          <div>
            <Input
              style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}
              fluid
              icon="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              iconPosition="left"
              onChange={(event, data) => {
                this.onSearchInputChange(event, data, searchedNodes);
              }}
            />
            <CheckboxTree
              nodes={searchedNodes}
              checked={checked}
              expanded={expanded}
              onCheck={this.onCheck}
              onExpand={this.onExpand}
              showNodeIcon={true}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Widget;
```

Comment: What's the output of console.log in renderTree?

Comment: Please update your question with a **much reduced** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: BInd the onCheck and onExpand methods  to the constructor

Comment: Have updated the question with a link to the sandbox

Comment: Ciao @li97, I have updated my answer modifying your codesandbox and it works. Let me know if it's not what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `shouldComponentUpdate` method:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.keyword !== nextState.keyword) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!_.isEqual(this.state.checked, nextState.checked)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (_.isEqual(this.state.expanded, nextState.expanded)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Since `renderTree` only changes `isDropdownExpanded` value, `shouldComponentUpdate` always returns `false`

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito This code is OP's code. I only showed what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: had to bring in if (
      !_.isEqual(this.state.isDropdownExpanded, nextState.isDropdownExpanded)
    ) {
      return true;
    } inisde  the shouldComponentUpdate

Answer (score 0):

If `shouldComponenetUpdate` returns true then your component re-renders, otherwise it dosen't.

In your code sandbox, it can be seen that every time you click on the dropdown, the `shouldComponenetUpdate` returns false for this condition

```
if (_.isEqual(this.state.expanded, nextState.expanded)) {
      return false;
    }
```

Either you need to change the state of this variable in your renderTree function or you need to re-write this condition as

```
 if (_.isEqual(this.state.isDropdownExpanded, nextState.isDropdownExpanded)) {
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ciao, to force a re-render in React you have to use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` function. Something like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.isDropdownExpanded !== nextState.isDropdownExpanded;
}
```

When you change `isDropdownExpanded` value, shouldComponentUpdate will be triggered and in case return is equal to true, component will be re-rendered. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-checkbox-tree-final-bqckw?file=/src/components/Widget.js) working example (based on your codesandbox).